# Search in belongs_to association in RoR, ElasticSearch with Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, elasticsearch, belongs-to, searchkick

I have two models:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :loyalty_cards
end

class LoyaltyCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue
  searchkick word_start: [:venue_name, :venue_name_from_relation]

  def search_data
    attributes.merge(
      venue_name_from_relation: self.venue(&:name)
    )
  end
end
```

LoyaltyCard has two fields:

```
venue_id: int #used for relation with venue if such venue exists
venue_name: string #or you can add venue name manually when creating loyalty card
```

I want to search both fields and tried the following tweak as suggested at Searchkick isses at GitHub (i.e. https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/112):
searchkick word_start: [:venue_name, :venue_name_from_relation]

```
  def search_data
    attributes.merge(
      venue_name_from_relation: self.venue(&:name)
    )
  end
```

It searches venue_name successfully, however does not in associated venue.

I also tried doing the following (and few other variations):

```
  def search_data
    {
      venue_name_from_relation: venue.map(&:name)
    }
  end
```

however it fails reindexing with nil class error.

Any ideas?

thanks,
Roman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the venue name correctly since it is a `belongs_to` association not a `has_many`

```
def search_data
  attributes.merge(
    venue_name_from_relation: self.venue_name_from_relation
  )
end

def venue_name_from_relation
  self.venue.name
end
```

Then use this to search

```
fields = ["venue_name", "venue_name_from_relation"]
LoyaltyCard.search(query, fields: fields, load: false)
```

or boost one field over another using (boost `venue_name` over `venue_name_from_relation`)

```
fields = ["venue_name^2", "venue_name_from_relation"]
LoyaltyCard.search(query, fields: fields, load: false)
```

Do not to forget to `reindex` before searching. `LoyaltyCard.reindex`

Comment: thanks Mohamed! I receive the following error while reindexing: LoyaltyCard Import (1.0ms)  {"count":4,"exception":["NoMethodError","undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"]}
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: If sometimes your venue relation can return nil the change `self.venue.name` to`self.venue.try(:name)`